# In same method changing two state, one is changed second not, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have dropdown and onSelect item dropdown should be closed.

Here is function which is called `onSelect` but think is that state `isOpen: false` will not be changed,

But state part: `selected: option` will be changed.

Does anyone know why?

```
onSelect = (option) => {
    this.setState({ selected: option, isOpen: false }, () => {
      this.props.onSelect(option);
    });
  };
```

Here is an entire component:

```
import React from 'react';
import onClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside';

class SimpleDropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: props.selectValue,
      isOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggleDropdown = () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-access-state-in-setstate
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  onSelect = (option) => {
    this.setState({ selected: option, isOpen: false }, () => {
      this.props.onSelect(option);
    });
  };

  handleClickOutside = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const { title, isLoading } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="simple-dropdown" onClick={this.toggleDropdown} role="button">
        <span className="dropdown-title">{title}:</span>
        <span>{selected.value}</span>
        {this.state.isOpen && !isLoading && (
          <ul className="dropdown-ul">
            {this.props.options.map((option) => (
              <li
                key={option.key}
                className={`dropdown-option ${option.value === selected.value ? 'hover' : ''}`}
              >
                <a className="option-btn" onClick={() => this.onSelect(option)} role="button">
                  {option.value}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default onClickOutside(SimpleDropdown);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `Event bubbling` a type of [Event propagation](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php).
Basically the click event on child element triggers the click event of parent element. you can fix this by calling `event.stopPropagation()` in the child element click handler.

Notice below `onClick` handler. the handler is getting the `event` object and then calling `stopPropagation` method.

```
<li
  key={option.key}
  className={`dropdown-option ${option.value === selected.value ? 'hover' : ''}`}
>
  <a className="option-btn" onClick={(event) => {event.stopPropagation(); this.onSelect(option)}} role="button">
                  {option.value}
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot on explanation

Comment: @MarkJames you are welcome :), let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 1):

`this.toggleDropdown` is being triggered even on selecting the value so add a check like this

```js
toggleDropdown = () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-access-state-in-setstate
    if (!this.state.isOpen) {
      this.setState({ isOpen: true });
    }
    
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Do you know maybe why that toggle is called when value is selected?

Comment: Because `li > a` being selected is child of parent button which has this trigger/onClick